# Custom template for displaying inner blog contents

Tags: views, nodes

I am trying to create a custom layout for my blog listing and blog content display pages.

The following url will display all the latest blogs based on the conditions that I have set.

http:///general-blog

When I click on the 'Read more' button corresponding to a button, it will display the full blog contents in another page.

Sample format : http:///general-blog/tourist-details

I am able to modify the layout of the page corresponding to blog listing. For this, I have created a custom tpl file : page--general-blog.tpl.php.

What I want is to create a new template file for displaying the contents of individual blogs.

The individual blog content display page is not entering - page--general-blog.tpl.php file. It's always using the template - page.tpl.php.

I tried creating separate tpl files like :

page--general-blog--%.tpl.php

But, the changes in this template is not getting effect in the individual blog content display page.

How should I move forward. Has someone had any similar situations?

Comment: did you flush the cache? it's a very important step! otherwise your new template file won't be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your template using 'theme_suggestion` in your page preprocess function. like the following:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  // Page template suggestion based on node type
  if (!empty($vars['node'])) {
    $node_type = $vars['node']->type;
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $node_type;
  }
}
```

if your node type is blog then your template will `page--node--blog.tpl.php`
Don't forget to ***clear cache*** after adding this code and your `tpl` file